# $.Deferred.then() function doesn't allow unknown number of time to call the function dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I came upon this script from Google search at [jQuery Deferred and Promise for sequential execution of synchronous and asynchronous funcitons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122227/jquery-deferred-and-promise-for-sequential-execution-of-synchronous-and-asynchro) .

This may solve my issue on executing the script in sequiental order.  But the problem I have with then() function is I have no way of knowing how many time can I call this function.   I can call the function a() 3 times, next time, I can call it 20 times, etc.  So, that won't work with then().  then() function doesn't allow the array stack.  So, what do you people do to to make this concept work?

```
fucntion a(counter)
{
    $deferred = $.Deferred();

    //Run some scripts here...
    alert(counter);

    $deferred.resolve();
    return $deferred;
}
function Test()
{
    var d = $.Deferred(), 
    p=d.promise();
    p.then(a(0)).then(a(1)).then(a(2));
    d.resolve();
    return d;
}

Test().done(function(){ alert('done'); }).fail(function() { alert('fail'); });
```

Comment: You are passing the `$deferred` returned by `a(N)` to `.then()`. Instead, you will need to pass a callback function, e.g. `.then(a)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you refer to calling `Test()` multiple times? What's wrong with that, what happens when you do this that you didn't expect? What do you mean by "*allow the array stack*"?

Comment: I updated the question, I mean a(), not Test()...

Comment: Yes, you're calling `a(0); a(1); a(2);` instantly together, which makes the async processes run concurrently.

Comment: Yes.  How many times to call it is random, the first time, it can be calling the function a() 3 times.  Later in the day, it can be calling the function a() 20 times.  How many time to call it is done randomly.  The $.Deferred.then() doesn't do random # of times to call the function a().

Comment: So what's the question? What concept are you trying to "make work"?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.  My question is how to add then() dynamically without knowing how many times the function a() is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is how to chain and unknown number of calls. In that case you can easily loop and just keep adding more `.then`. For example:

```
for (var i=0; i < someLimit; i++) {
    p = p.then(a(i));
}
```

That will chain the calls so they get called one after the other. If you wanted them to execute in parallel, then @jantimon's suggestion of using `.when` is the way to go.

This works because of how chaining works. A call to `.then` returns a promise so that you can call `.then` again on the returned promise. See: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, chaining having unknown number of calls.  I didn't know this would work.

Comment: I like your solution but this would also execute them in parallel, wouldn't it?

Comment: @jantimon: No. `.then` will be executed when the deferred is resolved. So they will execute one after the other. Not to be confused with `.when`

Comment: @MattBurland: `a(i)` doesn't return a function, but a promise. It will execute them in parallel, and not wait for anything…

Comment: @Bergi: Ah, yeah, I missed that part. But I'm not sure why they are returning a deferred in the first place.

Comment: @Bergi Okay, you're saying there's a better or simplier way?  If so then can you show me one?  I'm still learning as I'm trying to avoid the old fashioned callback ways.

Comment: @fletchsod: You can't avoid passing a callback to `then`, the advantage of promises is that you can unnest them. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18387432/1048572) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23650478/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`jQuery.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).
Please note that this would execute multiple asynchronous operations concurrently:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j7fyxsnw/1)</kbd>

Given you `a` function which returns an async promise:

```
function a(counter, $target) {
    var $deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $target.text($target.text() + ' ' + counter);
        $deferred.resolve();
    }, 1000);
    return $deferred;
}
```

In parallel:

```
function Test1() {
    return $.when($.map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], function (val, i) {
        return a(i, $('#test1'));
    }));
}

Test1().done(function () {
    $('#test1').css('font-weight', 'bold');
}).fail(function () {
    alert('fail');
});
```

To run it in sequence you will need a promiseLoop helper:

```
function promiseLoop(arr, callback) {
    return arr.reduce(function (previousPromise, val, i) {
        return previousPromise.then(function (resultArray) {
            return $.when(callback(val, i)).then(function (res) {
                return resultArray.concat([res]);
            });
        });
    }, $.when([]));
}

function Test2() {
    return promiseLoop([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], function (val, i) {
        return a(i, $('#test2'));
    });
}


Test2().done(function () {
    $('#test2').css('font-weight', 'bold');
}).fail(function () {
    alert('fail');
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will save a copy of this script if I need to run it in parrallel thread.

Comment: See the demo for an example which runs it in parallel or in sequence