# Functions executing in wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is a bit hard to explain, but I'll try my best. I have 3 tabs, one of which is active by default. Every time a tab is activated, an event fires. However, the tab headings are set in a function set earlier. My code is given below:

```
<script>
    var queues = {};

    $(document).ready(function(){

        getQueueData();
        $('.nav a[href="#queue1"]').tab('show');
    });

    function getQueueData(){

        $.post('interface/getqueues.php', function(data){


            var str = "#q";
            for (var i=0; i<data.data.length; i++){
                str += i;
                $(str).text(data.data[i]["name"]);
                queues[str] = data.data[i];
                console.log(queues[str]);
                str = "#q";   
            }
        });
    }

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on("shown.bs.tab", function(event){
        console.log("HELLO WORLD!");
        var elem = $(this).attr("id");
        var id = "#"+elem;
        console.log(queues);
    });


</script>
```

Now, the getQueueData() function should execute BEFORE the `shown.bs.tab` event is fired. This is necessary for the latter event to be able to access the values in the `queues` object. In fact, however, when the page is loading, the `shown.bs.tab` function is executing first, followed by getQueueData(). This means that in the `shown.bs.tab` method, `queues` is undefined the first time. I know it because the HELLO WORLD and an empty object is printing in the log before the `console.log(queues[str])` output. Does anyone know how I can make the getQueueData() execute completely before going to the `'shown.bs.tab'` event?

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a `promise`. Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122227/jquery-deferred-and-promise-for-sequential-execution-of-synchronous-and-asynchro

Comment: I believe you need to fire the `shown.bs.tab` event after you finish the async post, so call it at the end of the `$.post`s callback function.

Comment: Or just simply wrap your `$('a').on('shown.bs.tab')` in a function wrapper and call it from the successful post callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haha!

Pretty common question for beginners in javascript's asynchronous realm. :)
Welcome to the jungle mate. ;)

Here is the magic trick. Move your `$('.nav a[href="#queue1"]').tab('show');` inside `$.post` function. Put it after your `for` loop. :)

```
function getQueueData(){

        $.post('interface/getqueues.php', function(data){


            var str = "#q";
            for (var i=0; i<data.data.length; i++){
                str += i;
                $(str).text(data.data[i]["name"]);
                queues[str] = data.data[i];
                console.log(queues[str]);
                str = "#q";   
            }
            $('.nav a[href="#queue1"]').tab('show'); // << Triggre your show event here.
        });
    }
```

And everything will work great.

Will be updating this answer with explanation, soon. :)

==

EDIT:

Explanation.

Your concern, that `getQueueData()` should execute BEFORE `shown.bs.tab` is already fulfilled. However, it does appear that `getQueueData()` gets executed after your tabs show event.
Why is that?
Because you have an asynchronous call inside your `getQueueData()`. The script will make an API call to `interface/getqueues.php` and because it is asynchronous, it's heroic nature takes over and it doesn't wait until the server responds. It continues it's execution and returns from function `getQueueData()` and goes ahead and triggers the show event on your tabs (because the next statement after a call to `getQueueData` is your tabs's show statement.

When the server responds, it will trigger the callback you have specified in your `$.post` function call.
Therefore when this callback executes (which is after response is received from the server, the show event on your tabs has already taken place.
And this is why it seems like `getQueueData` is getting executed after tabs show event.
But in reality, it is executed before the tabs show event and the call back of `$.post` happens whenever it's necessary.

For more information, please read this [awesome guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38331/Simple-and-Practical-Introduction-to-Asynchronous).

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I am still trying to fully understand these asynchronous operations.

Comment: Once I did put it in the getQueueData() method, but after the $.post function. It was showing undefined.

Comment: @user3033194: Check the updated answer, let me know in case of any questions.

Comment: I see, so the call order is - first getQueueData() in which an asynchronous call is made, then the tabs function, then back to the callback function code for $.post in getQueueData() (when the async call is completed). Is this right?

Comment: OK, I got it now. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: True. :) Play around with it a little bit and you'll soon start loving this bavaviour, much more than traditional, straight forward programming. :)

Answer (score 2):

`post` is an asynchronous method. It means that its result is not necessarily get just after it is called. Javascript is such language that it won't wait for the result of an async method to continue to execute the rest of code.

Thus, you have to synchronizde your code by your own.

One thing that you can use for this purpose is `deferred object`. When you create it, it has a pending state. Whenever you resolve or reject over that object, you will get notified.

Below, notice how you could use it.

- You can wait for a function to be finished with a `deferred object`.

.

```
<script>
var queues = {};

var deferred = $.Deferred();

$(document).ready(function(){

    getQueueData();
    deferred.then(function() {
        $('.nav a[href="#queue1"]').tab('show');
    });

});

function getQueueData(){

    $.post('interface/getqueues.php', function(data){


        var str = "#q";
        for (var i=0; i<data.data.length; i++){
            str += i;
            $(str).text(data.data[i]["name"]);
            queues[str] = data.data[i];
            console.log(queues[str]);
            str = "#q";   
        }

        deferred.resolve();

    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for this forever!